# Mouse snapping back to upper right hand corner

Tags: unity, mouse

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Lenovo Erazer x510 desktop.  The mouse wants to be in the upper right hand corner of the screen. You can move it but it just snaps back into the corner.

I tried

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

and this works, but after about 2 or 3 minutes the mouse starts acting up again.

It also does it from the Live CD

I have tried different USB ports, and I am unable to even open terminal when in Unity. Even with the mouse unplugged, it is acting as there is one clicking.

```
sudo lightdm didn't help
```

Comment: And try the commands `xinput`. You will see a list of devices. Under `Virtual core pointer` there should be your mouse name, then with an `id=X`. Then run the command `xinput disable X` and `xinput enable X`. X is the id number.

Comment: Okay type Ctrl+Alt+F1, that should get you a command line.

Comment: same result.  I have been over 5 different forums and here and I still can not find an answer

Comment: I am out of ideas I am afraid. This is a bug, and needs to be reported on http://launchpad.net

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Lenovo Erazer X510, and I had the same problem 
both in Ubuntu 14.04 and Mint 17.1.  Since this machine doesn't even 
have a ps2 mouse (or touchpad), I simply enter the psmouse removal command alone:

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`

and this seems to have cleared up the problem -- the usb mouse is still working, and the erratic behaviour has gone away.

To make the change permanent, I added the line:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
```

to the file "/etc/rc.local", just above the line

```
exit 0
```

So far, so good.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Add 'i8042.noaux' to Linux parameters.

For example:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Login
3. Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and add the following line:

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.noaux"
4. Save using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> , then press <kbd>y</kbd>
5. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I discovered what worked for me was when the cursor got stuck in the lower left corner, I typed "xinput disable 9" and that frees the cursor and it works fine.  Under the 'xinput list' the item 9 is my slave pointer.  When I tried to disable the touch-pad as well my mouse still had problems, but just disabling the slave pointer it seems to have solved the problem.  Been successfully testing this for over a week so I believe this may be a permanent solution.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could create a script which runs the code: "sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse" continuously. Because earlier the question descriptions said "and this works, but after about 2 or 3 minutes the mouse starts acting up again.". Hope this helps!